# Where to put text on internet for using it in my app?

Tags: android, cloud

I'm developing an app for currency convertor for local users only. I need a cloud for saving a text file contains the rates between USD and other moneys.

Where can I easily save this text file? 
I searched on Google 2 days and didn't find one. Maybe I'm searching a wrong keywords.

I only need somewhere to save and update the text file.

Comment: I would suggest to use currency API's like provided by  http://fixer.io , so that you dont need to keep  your files/data up to date.

Comment: @VVJ: I think it's not useful for me because the rates is different from Bazar's rate. For example $100 -> 110,00 IQD  but in Bazar  $100 -> 122,000  IQD.

Answer (score -1):

Amazon S3 is a great place to store static text files.

https://aws.amazon.com/s3/